# droppable() background color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using jquery-ui's drag/drop, i am looking to have one element's (div) bg color change to the bg color of another element (div) when it is dragged and dropped on top of the first one. the background colors are dynamically retrieved from a data base, so in-line styling has to be used.
What options/arguments am i to used in .droppable({***})?

```
<?PHP echo  "<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        var " . $id . " = " . mysql row . "
        $('#first').draggable({revert:true});
        $('#second').draggable({revert:true});
        $('#third').draggable({revert:true});
        $('#fourth').draggable({revert:true});
        $('#fifth').draggable({revert:true});
        $('#target').droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).class('background-color', '" . $id . "');

        });
    });
    </script>"; ?>
```

Comment: you have problems with your quotes for a start ....`"<script type="text/javascript">` isnt going to work too well

Comment: thanx manseUK. I realize my issue with the double quotes, I also cannot expect "mysql row" do do anything for me either. My question is regarding .droppable() and background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of setting the `background-color` of a `droppable` to the `background-color` of the `draggable` that was dropped on it.

```
​$('​​​​​​​.draggable').draggable({
    revert: true
});
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accepts: '.draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var bgColor = $(ui.draggable).css('backgroundColor');
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', bgColor);
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
    }
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Live example**: http://jsfiddle.net/EyKnr/

If you're getting the `background-color` from a database you would just sub the `bgColor` variable in my example with the appropriate value.

Comment: this was very handy, I used a modified version of this code on my project. Thanx for your response.

Comment: If you don't need anything else and this helped you would you mind selecting my answer?

Comment: There is one more smalll issue i have left.
how do I limit $(ui.draggable) to only accepting from a certain class?
example...$(ui.draggable.class)?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question.  If you want to make it so that the draggable can only have one CSS class on it you could use ```$(ui.draggable).prop('className', 'whatever-the-class-you-want-is');```...?

Comment: i have draggable/droppable('.target') AND draggable('.swatch') elements(<div>). I only want the bg colour to be transfered from the draggable('.swatch') to the draggable/droppable('.target'), not draggable/droppable('.target') to draggable/droppable('.target').

Comment: You can wrap the logic in the ```drop``` event handler with an if check like ```if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('swatch'))```.  I updated the last target in your jsFiddle to show this - http://jsfiddle.net/uwVUA/5/.